# IndexOutOfRange error when accessing OleDbDataReader items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access

I have some sql that works fine in access 2010 and returns the correct values. However, in VB.NET, when I run it causes the above error in the while loop. dr.HasRows is returning '**TRUE**' but the var '**itm**' shows nothing in auto window. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can correct it. Thanks

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Max(Requests.[Request no]) AS [MaxOfRequest no], Requests.Customer, " &
                    "Max([Request Boxes].[Request no]) AS [MaxOfRequest no1], [Request Boxes].Customer " &
                    "FROM Requests, [Request Boxes] " &
                    "GROUP BY Requests.Customer, [Request Boxes].Customer " &
                    "HAVING (((Requests.Customer)='" & cmbCustomer.Text & "') AND (([Request Boxes].Customer)='" & cmbCustomer.Text & "')) " &
                    "ORDER BY Requests.Customer, [Request Boxes].Customer", oledbCnn)

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.HasRows Then <--- this returns true

                While dr.Read

                    itm = CStr(dr.Item("[MaxOfRequest no]")) <--- ERROR HERE
                    itm2 = CStr(dr.Item("[MaxOfRequest no1]"))

                End While

            End If
```

Comment: That `dr.HasRows` is true means there are *rows*. It doesn't mean that a particular *field* (like `[MaxOfRequest no]`) is present - which the error is trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the square brackets here:

```
itm = CStr(dr.Item("[MaxOfRequest no]"))
```

The square brackets are just delimiters in the SQL statement; they are not part of the column name itself. Try this instead:

```
itm = CStr(dr.Item("MaxOfRequest no"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much Gord